# GStreamer tutorial on Android getting 'Unsupported profile for video/mp4v-es' for RTSP stream

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm running the *GStreamer* tutorial 5 for Android from Eclipse. I've managed to make it use the latest GStreamer SDK (1.6.0) for Android, and I've got it running on a device.

The issue is as soon as the app opens I get in logcat the following:

```
10-13 16:22:42.033: W/VideoCapabilities(29740): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-13 16:22:42.056: I/VideoCapabilities(29740): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
10-13 16:22:42.064: W/VideoCapabilities(29740): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-13 16:22:42.066: E/GStreamer+amc(29740): 0:00:00.264301198 0xb4bed6e0 gstamc.c:1716:scan_codecs Decoder codec has unknown color formats, ignoring
10-13 16:22:42.067: E/GStreamer+amc(29740): 0:00:00.264932917 0xb4bed6e0 gstamc.c:1716:scan_codecs Decoder codec has unknown color formats, ignoring
10-13 16:22:42.068: E/GStreamer+amc(29740): 0:00:00.265640521 0xb4bed6e0 gstamc.c:1716:scan_codecs Decoder codec has unknown color formats, ignoring
10-13 16:22:42.068: E/GStreamer+amc(29740): 0:00:00.266278906 0xb4bed6e0 gstamc.c:1716:scan_codecs Decoder codec has unknown color formats, ignoring
10-13 16:22:42.073: I/VideoCapabilities(29740): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

Further down I get this line over and over:

```
10-13 16:22:42.762: W/GStreamer+tutorial-5(29740): 0:00:00.959787084 0xa12f2a60 jni/tutorial-5.c:137:refresh_ui Could not query current position (normal for still pictures)
```

The video never plays and is always in the `Paused` state, even when I press `Play`.

I've searched elsewhere for this problem and all I've found is [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Using-GStreamer-as-RTSP-Client-td4670048.html), and it's also unresolved.

Comment: Did you find any solution/answer to this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the GStreamer tutorial 5 as a starting point for GStreamer for Android, a more up-to-date way is using the Gradle project [here](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-player) since Eclipse has been pretty much abandoned and Android Studio/Gradle are the new standards. It was created by a prominent contributor to GStreamer.

1. Download the "android" folder from the Github link
   above, then put it wherever you want your project to be.
2. Download the [GStreamer SDK](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/) (I used
   gstreamer-1.0-android-arm-1.8.0)
3. Create a new environment variable (if you're using Windows) called GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID that points to the GStreamer SDK
4. In Android Studio go to File->New->Import Project and follow the
   steps to import the "android" folder as a new project.

From here the project should build and run.